# Unit test class annotated by @Transactional and implications to detach/evict in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, junit4, dozer

I'm struggling with a problem I and can not find out proper solution or even a cause neither in hibernate docs, sources nor S/O.

I have spring/hibernate application with DAO-Service-RPC layers, where DAO provides Hibernate entities and Service DTOs for RPC. Therefore I'm converting (mapping by Dozer) Entities to DTOs in service methods and mapping DTOs back to Entities there as well.

Mapping is as follows (not full method, checking ommited):

```
@Transactional
public updateAuthor(Author author) {
    AuthorEntity existingEntity = this.authorDao.findById(author.getId());
    this.authorDao.detach(existingEntity);
    this.authorAssembler.toEntity(author, existingEntity, null);
    this.authorDao.merge(existingEntity);
}
```

I have unit test classes annotated by `@Transactional` to avoid test data bleeding. Now, I realized, that there is something, I don't understand, going on in Service.

When I have my test class annotated by `@Transactional`, calling `detach()` seems to work (i.e. Hibernate is not reporting *org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*, but `@Version` number on entity is not incremented properly (as if the parent (unit test)) TX was still holding on.

When I remove my test class annotation, mapping throws *org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection* - which makes sense on it's own, because the entity is detached from session. What I don't understand is, **why this exception is NOT thrown when the test class is annotated**. As I understand, entity is detached from the current session in both cases.

My other question is - assuming the entity is behaving correctly - **how to avoid missing such errors in unit tests and avoid test bleeding as well**, as it seems to be, this type of error manifests only with unannotated test class.

Thank you!

(JUnit4, Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.1.Final)